# Origin of the phrase "There's a fine line between A and B"

Tags: history

For instance, Oscar Levant says

> "There's a fine line between genius and insanity. I have erased this line."
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Levant)

but I'm not sure if he is the original maker of this saying. For instance there are many other examples of it's usage : There's a fine line between pleasure and pain, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is no specific origin of the phrase as suggested by [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/34/messages/1259.html) :

> - 'There's a fine line between...' means that the two things mentioned are very close. For example, there's a fine line between genius and madness, or love and hate.
> - **These fine lines may be the origin of the phrase, or at least the source of its popularity.**
>
>   *"Great wits are sure to madness near alli'd*
>     ***And thin partitions*** do their bounds divide."
> - John Dryden 1631-1700 in Alexander's Feast 1.163

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20fine%20line%20between%2C%20a%20thin%20line%20between%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20fine%20line%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20thin%20line%20between%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the phrase became more and more popular from the beginning of the 20th century.

One of my favourite quotes:

“a thin line separates love from hate, success from failure, life from death, a line as difficult to walk as a razor’s edge”. ( W. Somerset Maugham)